# comparing GWT with its comparable tech

Tags: gwt

I am looking for a Technology that I can compare with GWT. 
I was thinking about comparing GWT vs Ruby on Rail. But I am not sure if it is the best compare to pick.
If any one can give me some hints, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GWT:**

`GWT architecture` needs deep understanding to be used completely. It is built for `advanced users`.

**Rails:**

`Rails` is simple and aimed at writing less code. Suitable for beginners in `web development.`

Here is a complete [PDF](http://www.psl.cs.columbia.edu/classes/cs6125-s11/presentations/2010/Presentation_Monal_Sanghvi.pdf) about comparison .

Comment: Wow.  That hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to compare GWT to anything else.

The main idea behind GWT was to leverage existing tooling: debuggers, IDEs (refactoring, etc.), static analysis tools (findbugs, checkstyle, PMD), etc. The goal is not to provide a true emulation of Java in JavaScript; being able to use any existing Java library with GWT is a non-goal.

So, what is GWT?

- GWT is a *transpiler* to JavaScript, much like CoffeeScript, TypeScript, Script#, Emscripten, Haxe and [many](http://altjs.org/) [more](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS).

  - Unlike many others though, GWT development runs Java in a JVM rather than compiling to JS (Dart with its Dartium and dart2js works similarly), which allows you to use a Java debugger, and tools like JRebel for hot code replacement.
  - The compilation process is also *pluggable* with code/resource generators (*deferred binding*). This, combined with the static typing of Java, makes it possible to use dependency-injection tools such as GIN (Guice for GWT)
- GWT is also an extensive library:

  - client-server communication protocols: GWT-RPC and RequestFactory (RequestFactory can also be used from a Java client, such as an Android application; RequestFactory can also be used to consume JSON-RPC services)
  - JSON marshalling through AutoBeans
  - widgets, which makes people sometimes compare GWT to Swing in the way to build UIs (though if you build GWT UIs like you do Swing UIs, you're doomed)
  - UiBinder is similar to Flex's MXML, .NET's XAML, or Gnome's Glade; but can also be used to output HTML rather than build widgets, which makes it more like… AngularJS maybe?
  - SafeHtmlTemplates can be seen as similar to Mustache.js
  - CssResources are similar to Closure Stylesheet, or Sass or Less, though with fewer features
  - Editors are somehow comparable to AngularJS bindings (see discussion at https://plus.google.com/114156500057804356924/posts/LSNj2zTZo78)

Depending on the facet you're looking at, you can compare GWT with many other tools; but most of all, GWT is a *client-side* tool, so one thing you **can't** compare it with is Rails.

Comment: Thanks Thomas , Very help full

Answer (score 0):

Simple JavaScript MV* frameworks are numerous and easy to compare. However, at the enterprise scale - there are far fewer frameworks and each are very different. A few others:

- ExtJS - A complex and enterprise scale JavaScript framework
- TypeScript - A new language developed by Microsoft that is strongly typed and compiles to JavaScipt
- Closure - A Google technology for type-checking JavaScript

As you can see, none of these are quite the same as GWT, yet all are targeted at enterprise scale JavaScript development.